# How to defind data member in c# wcf

Tags: c#, wcf

I have made data member look like this

```
public class Logon
{
    [DataMember]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public TemplateStatusInfo Status;      
}      

public class TemplateStatusInfo
{
    [DataMember]
    one;
    two;          
}
```

When I call the service I need some thing like this

```
OOP.Client oClient  = new OOP.Client();
oClient.Status = OOP.TemplateStatusInfo.one;
//or 
oClient.Status = OOP.TemplateStatusInfo.two;
```

Comment: What defines OOP.Client class? I thought you would have to instantiate Logon class.

Comment: And your question is....?

Answer (score 1):

Change your `TemplateStatusInfo` class to an enumeration.

```
[DataContract]
public enum TemplateStatusInfo
{
    [EnumMember]
    one;        
    [EnumMember]
    two;          
}
```